# how to customize chartjs

Tags: javascript, html, css, charts

I'm trying to achieve this look for my chartjs:

[image]

And here is my chartjs:

[image]

Here is my `script tag` for chartjs:

```
    var ctx = document.getElementById("myChart");
    var myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
        type: 'pie',
        data: {
            labels: labels_most_forked,
            datasets: [{
                label: '# of Votes',
                data: values_most_forked,
                backgroundColor: [
                    'rgba(255, 99, 132, 1)',
                    'rgba(54, 162, 235, 1)',
                    'rgba(255, 206, 86, 1)',
                    'rgba(75, 192, 192, 1)',
                    'rgba(153, 102, 255, 1)',
                    'rgba(255, 159, 64, 1)'
                ],
                borderColor: [
                    'rgba(255,99,132,1)',
                    'rgba(54, 162, 235, 1)',
                    'rgba(255, 206, 86, 1)',
                    'rgba(75, 192, 192, 1)',
                    'rgba(153, 102, 255, 1)',
                    'rgba(255, 159, 64, 1)'
                ],
                borderWidth: 1
            }]
        },
        options: {
            responsive: true,
            maintainAspectRatio: false,
            legend: {
                position: 'right',
               verticalAlign: 'top',
            }
        },
        tooltips: {
            mode: 'label'
        },
      });

<canvas id="myChart" width="180" height="180"></canvas>
```

I tried to  `verticalAlign: 'top'` for my labels but it's not working and how to make my chart looks bigger?

after add

```
responsive: true,
maintainAspectRatio: false,
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Your charts are very likely missing the `maintainAspectRatio` and `responsive` options along with the `width` and `height` settings in the canvas.

These two settings default both to `true` which makes it look good on mobile but can cause the pie to look extremely small. See for example this: https://jsfiddle.net/adelriosantiago/bzm38s7u/6/

[image]

Add the settings,

```
options: {
  responsive: true,
  maintainAspectRatio: false,
}
```

Optionally define a width and height in the canvas like `<canvas id="myChart" width="400px" height="500px"></canvas>`.

You should get a pie that uses most of the space regardless of the size of the container. Like this: https://jsfiddle.net/adelriosantiago/r2h79vto/2/

[image]

More info on these settings here: https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/general/responsive.html

Comment: i tried that but like my chart like the picture i Updated

Comment: and when I changed `maintainAspectRatio: true,` nothing change

Comment: Can you recreate the chart in a JSFiddle?